# Pushed segue scene works, modal segue scene doesn't?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am manually calling a push segue which works great. The new TableView scene comes up, the  custom nav buttons in the nav controller work perfect.

However, I want it to be a modal segue instead. So, I changed the type to Modal and embedded the new scene in a Navigation Controller. The new scene comes up, however the scene won't go away when the cancel button is tapped.

Any ideas why? Thanks.

Comment: what actions are you calling form the buttons? Is it possible the actions are invalid for modals (e.g. popViewControllerAnimated)?

Comment: Oh! Of course. I frequently forget I need to change that call when using modal.

Comment: then please correct your question. it's not that *the action methods aren't being called*, they are being called but nothing is happening.

Comment: Corrected. I had originally thought it wasn't calling the method at all. Not sure how I missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Push** segue adds a new view controller to the navigation stack in which the presenting view controller is also contained. That's why the navigation bar works in that case.

A **Modal** segue doesn't add the view controller to the navigation stack, it adds it as a child of the presenting view controller, so in this case there is no defined navigation.

If you want your nav bar to work on the modally presented controller you are going to have to wire up the actions manually (e.g.: make the "Back" button dismiss the modally presented controller).

Also, as pointed out by @Edwin Iskandar, make sure you call the proper dismiss actions on the view controller, meaning: `popViewControllerAnimated` won't work on a modally presented view controller, instead you should call `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`

**P.S.:** Note that `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated` is deprecated in favor of `dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) completion:^(void)completion` for iOS 6

Comment: The scene already has the buttons wired. That's why they worked with the push segue. I guess I didn't make that clear in the original question. Updated the question a little to make this more clear.